# Wordpress - how to use authentication for other code?

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I want to setup WordPress and use it's authentication for outside scripts.

For example, I'll have a script here:

```
http://www.domain.com/simplescript
```

Instead of adding custom user and password login, I thought it would be great simply to add a line at the top of the code, something like a is_user_logged_in check.

I read somewhere this can be done, the only extra being to add `require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/wp-blog-header.php');` at the top...

**BUT**... the page says the code *has* to be in the theme folder - which I would prefer not to have this restriction. I want to have my code anywhere on the website.

My code isn't all that complex - but does need other files + may or may not need folders and sub folders

Any ideas on how I can do what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to require 'wp-load.php' in your seperate PHP file. wp-load.php is in the root of your WordPress installation. You should modify the path if the script is somewhere else. Like this,

```
<?php

    require_once 'wp-load.php';

    if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        // true
    } else {
        // false
    }

?>
```